# Invert linear axis in Visiblox chart

Tags: c#, wpf, visiblox

Is it possible to invert a LinearAxis in a Visiblox chart? For example, if a linear axis is being used as the Y axis and the minimum and maximum axis values are 1 and 10, then I would want the axis to be flipped so that 1 is at the top of the axis and 10 is at the bottom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The next version, due out in the next month or two, will have a ReverseAxis property that will allow this functionality.

Alternatively, it is possible to implement your own IAxis to do this. You would need to implement new versions of the various RenderPosition methods, such as GetDataValueAsRenderPositionWithoutZoom, to calculate the correct 'inverted' render position.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just to follow up on this comment: [http://www.visiblox.com/blog/2011/07/visiblox-charts-2-1-a-sneak-peak][1]


  [1]: http://www.visiblox.com/blog/2011/07/visiblox-charts-2-1-a-sneak-peak